# How to populate column with list from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have three tables: `STORES`, `STATES`, and `STORES_STATES`.

- **`STORES`** contains records of individual stores
- **`STATES`** just contains a list of all 50 US states
- **`STORES_STATES`** is a join table that contains pairs of stores and states to show which stores are available in which states

Consider the following tables (*can't figure out how to format an ASCII table here*):

[image: table screenshot]

What I need is a SELECT statement that will return each store in one column, and a list of states in another:

[image: table screenshot]

How do I combine the results of a subquery into a single column like this?

I would imagine it would be similar to this query:

```
SELECT
  STORE_NAME,
  (SELECT STATE_ABV FROM STORES_STATES WHERE STORES_STATES.STORE_ID = STORES.ID)
FROM STORES;
```

But this obviously fails since the subquery returns more than one result.

Comment: How about `STUFF`

Comment: @Sami because it's `FOR XML` that does the tricks, not `STUFF`

Comment: @MatBailie Yup that's it.

Comment: Tangential comment. I use the [ASCII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) site to format tabular data for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT s.store_name, STUFF(ss.state_abv, 1, 1, '') AS States
FROM stores s CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT ', '+ss.state_abv
       FROM stores_state ss
       WHERE ss.store_id = s.id
       FOR XML PATH('')
     ) ss(state_abv);
```

Comment: This "works," but seems to return the STATES column with <STATE_ABV> tags around each state.

Comment: @Zephyr. . . I forget to add `', '` in `APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

your two options are either the STRING_AGG function in the newest versions of SQL Server, or using an XML concatenation technique as described in this answer:

[How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv?rq=1)

The XML method is messy-looking in your code and difficult to remember - I always have to look up the syntax - but it's actually quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF()` function along side with `FOR XML PATH('')` and join both tables on `StoreID`

```
CREATE TABLE Stores
(
  ID INT,
  StoreName VARCHAR(45)
);

CREATE TABLE States
(
  StoreID INT,
  StateABV VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO Stores VALUES
(1, 'Wolmart'), (2, 'Costco'), (3, 'Croegers');

INSERT INTO States VALUES
(1, 'NY'), 
(1, 'WY'),
(1, 'MI'),
(2, 'AL'),
(2, 'GA'),
(2, 'TX'),
(3, 'FL');

SELECT SR.StoreName,
       STUFF(
              (
                SELECT ',' + ST.StateABV
                FROM States ST
                WHERE ST.StoreID = SR.ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
           ) State
FROM Stores SR;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------+----------+
| StoreName |  State   |
+-----------+----------+
| Wolmart   | NY,WY,MI |
| Costco    | AL,GA,TX |
| Croegers  | FL       |
+-----------+----------+
```